# reactor.netty error when depending on spring-boot-starter-webflux

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, spring-webflux, spring-webclient, reactor-netty

I have a java project based on Spring framework, which is based on gradle build tool.

The gradle configures a parent project Par and sub-project Child.

The Par project has the build.gradle setting spring framework boot version as 2.2.6:

```
plugins {         
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.6.RELEASE'     
    ...
}
```

The Child project has the build.gradle as below:

```
ext.versions = [     
    spring: '5.2.9.RELEASE',     
    spring_boot: '2.2.10.RELEASE',
    slf4j: '1.7.30',     
    grpc_helpers_java: '^19.0'     
]
```

I tried to use WebClient of spring framework, so I added spring-boot-starter-webflux dependency to the build.gradle file of the child project as below:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-webflux', version: versions.spring_boot
    ...
}
```

I don't have other code change yet.

However, although the build passed, the bootRun from the Par project failed with the following error:

```
An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.netty.NettyReactiveWebServerFactory.createHttpServer(NettyReactiveWebServerFactory.java:163)

The following method did not exist:

    'reactor.netty.transport.Transport reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServer.runOn(reactor.netty.resources.LoopResources)'

The method's class, reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServer, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/XXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.projectreactor.netty/reactor-netty/0.9.12.RELEASE/41022546d07f1499fb9d8617bba4a1a89d3549db/reactor-netty-0.9.12.RELEASE.jar!/reactor/netty/http/server/HttpServer.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServer: file:/C:/Users/XXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.projectreactor.netty/reactor-netty/0.9.12.RELEASE/41022546d07f1499fb9d8617bba4a1a89d3549db/reactor-netty-0.9.12.RELEASE.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServer
```

I think the transitive dependency reactor.netty has a version of 0.9.12 is correct based on the spring-boot-starter-webflux version of 2.2.10. So I do not understand why the bootRun is trying to look for reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServer.runOn method which doesn't exist for reactor.netty version 0.9.12

Thank you very much.

Comment: why do you have different spring boot versions declared

Comment: I am not sure, these build.gradle files are not originally written by me. But even if I changed the versions to the same, i.e. 2.2.10, the error will be the same

Comment: im no pro at gradle but ClassNotFound and MethodNotFound is usually because of dependency problems, and that you are pulling in multiple versions of the same dependency and the build system will generally default to the lowest version which then doesnt include that method you are calling etc.

Comment: The system does pull reactor.netty has a version of 0.9.12, which is the transitive dependency of spring boot 2.2.10 (the higher version)

Comment: When running the `bootRun` task from within the child module what do you get as an output?

Comment: There is no bootRun task in the child project